# Power Pivot Table - How can I determine where the data for a table came from?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have an Excel workbook with a Power Pivot model. When I open the workbook and select Manage Data Model, I'm taken to the Power Pivot screen. There are seven tables compromising the model. I'm trying to determine where data is coming from for one of the tables. When I click on the tab associated with the table, and select the Design menu option, the Table Properties button is disabled. However, there is no link icon in the tab name indicating a link to another table in the model. So, my question is, in this case, how do I determine where this data came from?

The original designer of this model isn't readily available at the moment.

Comment: Have you checked the `Connections` in `Data` card as the data may be coming from external sources and loaded into `Data Model`.

Comment: Try checking the query editor too.